# Correct way to do a redirect after posting through axios in a vuex store

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vuex

I am using nuxtjs, axios and vuex to post from a form component to post my data to my backend.

When posted I'd like to redirect to the view record screen and populate it with the returned information using the ID to navigate there

so my path might be /cases/14325 (if 14325 is the id returned once created)

What is the correct way to do this please

I have the following code in my vuex store

```
export const state = () => ({
    cases: []
  })

  // ***  MUTATIONS  ***
  export const mutations = {
    add(state, newCase ) {
    state.cases.push(newCase)
  },

  }

  // ***  ACTIONS  ***
  export const actions = {
    addCase(context, newCase) {
    const createdCase = {
        ...newCase
    }
    axios.post("http", createdCase)
    .then(result => {
        context.commit('add', {...createdCase, id: result.data.name})
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
    },
  }
```

In my component I have the following

```
    import { mapMutations, mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {

  data () {
    return {
      newCase: {
        caseName: '',
        summary: '',
        status: 'live',
      },
    }
  },

  methods: {

     ...mapActions([
      'addCase' 
    ]),
    onSubmit() {
      // Save the post
      this.$store.dispatch('addCase').then(path => {
        this.$router.redirect(path)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })  
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

How do i return the new id from my store please and replace cases/1 with '/cases/' + new id?

Thanks for the help as always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe is will be enough when you improve your action this way:

```
addCase(context, newCase) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    const createdCase = {...newCase}
    axios.post('http', createdCase).then(result => {
      context.commit('add', {...createdCase, id: result.data.name})
      resolve(/*path*/)
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
      reject(/*reason*/)
    })
  })
}
```

And then you use it this way:

```
this.$store.dispatch('addCase', context).then(path => {
  this.$router.redirect(path)
})
```

Comment: Many Thanks, this gives the error ReferenceError: context is not defined.  I added resolve('/cases/' + createdCase.id)

Comment: Did you defined it in export const actions? Because I see no reason to have context undefined in my example. See Vuex actions documentation, they are using similar example. Action is returning Promise and in component you are using 'then' callback.

Comment: I imported as follows import { mapMutations, mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex' and i get the error [vuex] unknown action type: addCase
TypeError: this.$store.dispatch(...) is undefined

Comment: Are you using modules? Because in your previous code you was calling addCase action as this.$store.dispatch('cases/addCase', ...)

Comment: Yes, I am using modules, tried 'cases/addCase' but same error

Comment: missed one, thats been updated, now get _this.$router.redirect is not a function

Comment: if i console.log('/cases/' + createdCase.id) i also get /cases/undefined

Comment: i changed resolve('/cases/' + result.data.name) which now gives correct result but still get _this.$router.redirect is not a function

Comment: Does it make a different I am using Nuxt?

Comment: Try this.$router.push() or this.$router.replace()

Comment: I thought I had, doesn't show up yet though as I don't have enough reputations yet